# System.Data.SqLite not working on release mode in visual studio 2017 community edition

Tags: c#, windows-services, visual-studio-2017, system.data.sqlite

I'm developing a windows service which uses System.Data.SQLite (NuGet Package). In Debug mode service is running well but in release mode, after installing the service on windows 10 it didn't work. Here is a snapshot of the error when i tried to start the service

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition on windows 10 and developing service on .NET 4 framework. I got these from the FAQ at https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q3. But I'm not sure that I'm this having trouble because of the community edition of visual studio.

> Currently, Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015 are
>   supported, including the "Express" editions; however, in order to
>   build the entire solution, including the necessary native code, the
>   "Professional" edition (or higher) is required.

Here is my SQLite Manager class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;

namespace JST3X
{
    public class SQLiteDBManager
    {
        private string dbFullPath;
        private string DBConnectionString;
        private string DBPassword;
        private SQLiteConnection DBConnction;

        public SQLiteDBManager(string FullFilePath, string Password = null, Boolean CreateIfNotExist = false)
        {
            this.dbFullPath = FullFilePath;
            if ((!File.Exists(this.dbFullPath)) && CreateIfNotExist)
            {
                SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(this.dbFullPath);
            }
            else if (!File.Exists(this.dbFullPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(this.dbFullPath + " not found!");
                return;
            }

            if (Password != null)
            {
                this.DBPassword = Password;
                this.DBConnectionString = "Data source=" + this.dbFullPath + ";Password=" + this.DBPassword;
                this.DBConnction = new SQLiteConnection(this.DBConnectionString);
                this.DBConnction.SetPassword(this.DBPassword);
            }
            else
            {
                this.DBConnectionString = "Data source=" + this.dbFullPath;
                this.DBConnction = new SQLiteConnection(this.DBConnectionString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I was trying to access the SQLite database through windows service program and the database was created using windows form application. The WFA was accessing the directory **C:\Users\<*user*>\AppData\Local** to store files while service application was accessing directory **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local** to look for files.

I solved (somehow fixed) the problem by storing the directory in environment variables so that both programs will use the same absolute directory. One can post the elegant way of solving this problem.

Comment: You're doing too much work on startup.  When your service starts, start running your work on a background thread, using the thread pool.

Comment: I've successfully developed three windows service project before but this time I'm using System.Data.SQLite which causes the problem. Is there any other options available because right now I'm not familiar with the thread pool.

Comment: You've got a limited amount of time for the OnStart method to return. That's set in stone. You cannot get around that fact.

Comment: @ikdhruw: I am facing a similar issue due to the System.Data.SQLite assembly in the release mode. My project is WPF and I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: If you know the solution , Kindly post here.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SahirSaiyed The problem was the SQLite database I was trying to access wasn't there actually. If you want more details I can post my solution as a answer.

Comment: @SahirSaiyed I found out that service was not looking the database at the right directory and page that helped me was similar to this one https://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accou

Comment: @Pandi Yeah, It's too late. I hope you already found out the solution if not you can see it in comments. Meanwhile I'm collecting more information so that I can post a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have threading issue with my code.